# Flexbox: text not shrinking proportionally

Tags: html, css, flexbox, viewport-units

For a website I am creating, I managed to recreate the company logo (which is fairly basic) in Flexbox/CSS. I found the Flexbox CSS somewhere on the internet, but don't recall where. It's mainly untouched, my own styles are at the bottom under /* My Styles */

So it works, basically - but when I resize my browser window to fake tablet-size-screen of phone-size-screen, the text inside the logo starts to shrink when the screen size gets smaller than 568px.

There is some CSS

```
@media all and (max-width: 568px) {
.col-span-1,
.col-span-3,
.col-span-4,
.col-span-5 {
flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

that seems to have something to do with the text getting smaller, but I just don't understand. Until a few days ago, I had not heard about flexbox so I am no guru when it comes to that.

> I need the text inside the logo to grow and shrink proportionally no matter what the screen size is, but I also need the flexboxes to
>   shove below each other when the screen size gets smaller than 568px.

Can you guys help me out on this one?

Thank in advance for your help and time, it's very much appreciated!

Kind regards,

Fieke Bazelmans

*PS In the Code snippet below, the result-frame is smaller than 568px (on my MacBook Pro 13"), so I'm not sure you guys can see how the logo should be looking, therefor I'll add a link to a picture of the logo to make sure you understand my crappy explanation ;)*

[Picture of original logo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nlflmxfip065pbv/LOGO-%20Durlinger-financieel-beheer-860kb.jpg.jpg?dl=0)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

.row {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 1 8%;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-logo {
  flex: 1 1 8%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* nested grids */

.row .row,
.row.nested {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
}


/* full width grids */

.row.wide-fit {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}


/* center grids */

.row.center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.center .col {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}


/* columns widths */

.col-span-1 {
  flex-basis: 8.3333%;
}

.col-span-2 {
  flex-basis: 16.6666%;
}

.col-span-3 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.col-span-4 {
  flex-basis: 33.3333%;
}

.col-span-5 {
  flex-basis: 41.6666%;
}

.col-span-6 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.col-span-7 {
  flex-basis: 58.3333%;
}

.col-span-8 {
  flex-basis: 66.6666%;
}

.row .col-logo.col-span-8 {}

.col-span-9 {
  flex-basis: 75%;
}

.col-span-10 {
  flex-basis: 83.3333%;
}

.col-span-11 {
  flex-basis: 91.6666%;
}

.col-span-12 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}


/* examples */

.fixed-width {
  flex: 0 0 500px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
}

@media all and (max-width: 568px) {
  .col-span-1,
  .col-span-2,
  .col-span-3,
  .col-span-4,
  .col-span-5 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
  .col-span-6,
  .col-span-7,
  .col-span-8,
  .col-span-9,
  .col-span-10,
  .col-span-11 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .nested .col {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}


/* eye candy */

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.row {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.col {
  background-color: #999999;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


/* My Styles */

#header-logo-text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header-logo-container {
  min-width: 0;
  background-color: #eb5d60;
  padding: 1vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-logo-container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.logo-whiteborder {
  border: 0.4vw solid white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo-whiteborder:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.header-logo-text-big {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  src: url('../font-gill-sans.woff');
  font-size: 3.3vw;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-width: 0;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  padding-right: 1vw;
}

.header-logo-text-small {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  letter-spacing: 0.12em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 1.7vw;
  margin-bottom: 1.7vw;
  min-width: 0;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  padding-right: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link href="css/durlinger-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-logo col-span-4 header-logo-container">
      <div class="col-span-11 logo-whiteborder">
        <div id="header-logo-text-container">
          <div class="header-logo-text-big">Durlinger</div>
          <div class="header-logo-text-small">financieel beheer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-logo col-span-8">
      <!-- text beside logo -->

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looking at the first line of code in the post, flex basis is set to 50% so when you resize under that media query width, things will shrink since it is 50%

Comment: Yes...I realize that the culprit is in there somewhere, I just don't know how to fix it. If I take that code out (already tried that), the logo stays perfect when resizing a screen, BUT the flex boxes no longer display vertically at a smaller screen-size. And I do want them to do that AND have a logo that stays perfect.

Comment: You can always override styles on certain elements. If you can create a simplified example of this in a fiddle or something, I am pretty sure this is a fairly simple issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your font size using viewport units `vw`, you need to change them too with your media query, to something like this, which I also added to your `@media` rule in below snippet

```
.header-logo-text-big {
  font-size: 13.2vw;
}
.header-logo-text-small {
  font-size: 5.6vw;
}
```

Also, for media query's to properly override previous rules they should be last in your CSS

Stack snippet

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

.row {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 1 8%;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-logo {
  flex: 1 1 8%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* nested grids */

.row .row,
.row.nested {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
}


/* full width grids */

.row.wide-fit {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}


/* center grids */

.row.center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.center .col {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}


/* columns widths */

.col-span-1 {
  flex-basis: 8.3333%;
}

.col-span-2 {
  flex-basis: 16.6666%;
}

.col-span-3 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.col-span-4 {
  flex-basis: 33.3333%;
}

.col-span-5 {
  flex-basis: 41.6666%;
}

.col-span-6 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.col-span-7 {
  flex-basis: 58.3333%;
}

.col-span-8 {
  flex-basis: 66.6666%;
}

.row .col-logo.col-span-8 {}

.col-span-9 {
  flex-basis: 75%;
}

.col-span-10 {
  flex-basis: 83.3333%;
}

.col-span-11 {
  flex-basis: 91.6666%;
}

.col-span-12 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}


/* examples */

.fixed-width {
  flex: 0 0 500px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
}


/* eye candy */

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.row {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.col {
  background-color: #999999;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


/* My Styles */

#header-logo-text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header-logo-container {
  min-width: 0;
  background-color: #eb5d60;
  padding: 1vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-logo-container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.logo-whiteborder {
  border: 0.4vw solid white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo-whiteborder:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.header-logo-text-big {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  src: url('../font-gill-sans.woff');
  font-size: 3.3vw;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-width: 0;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  padding-right: 1vw;
}

.header-logo-text-small {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  letter-spacing: 0.12em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 1.7vw;
  margin-bottom: 1.7vw;
  min-width: 0;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  padding-right: 1vw;
}

@media all and (max-width: 568px) {
  .col-span-1,
  .col-span-2,
  .col-span-3,
  .col-span-4,
  .col-span-5 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
  .col-span-6,
  .col-span-7,
  .col-span-8,
  .col-span-9,
  .col-span-10,
  .col-span-11 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .nested .col {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }

  .header-logo-text-big {
    font-size: 13.2vw;
  }
  .header-logo-text-small {
    font-size: 5.6vw;
  }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link href="css/durlinger-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-logo col-span-4 header-logo-container">
      <div class="col-span-11 logo-whiteborder">
        <div id="header-logo-text-container">
          <div class="header-logo-text-big">Durlinger</div>
          <div class="header-logo-text-small">financieel beheer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-logo col-span-8">
      <!-- text beside logo -->

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I ran the snippet, viewed it full page and YES!! I would have never guessed that it was in the font-size /vw. Have been trying out tuff for literally days now, so I am very happy with your answer and will update my code straight after dinner. It should work, as your code does too. If not, I'll be back ;)